# Why am I able to access files despite not pinning them?

Tags: ipfs

I'm running an in browser instance of `js-ipfs` on a web page. When a user clicks an upload button, they can select a file which will then be added to the IPFS node. I've disabled automatic pinning in my `.add()` call by passing `{pin: false}`. I've confirmed that the node is not pinning the file by calling `ipfs.pin.ls()` and seeing an empty array.

However, if I `.cat()` the file hash on another computer, I am able to retrieve it.

I've made sure that these are not files that have been uploaded before by  generating new screencasts in Quicktime.

What's going on? I thought files needed to be pinned in order to be accessible? Or is my file going to some intermediary gateway first?

Answer (score 2):

When you add a file, it's still cached locally for some time, namely until the garbage collector runs. `pin` just adds hashes to a "do not garbage collect" list. This is likely the effect you're seeing.

I've also heard reports of the official gateway, which you connect to by default, pre-loading added content for faster retrieval, so it could have been cached there as well.